# Keyspace Notification LREM

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I can see keyspace notifications when I call SET and DEL commands but I don't see the same for Lists. For example

RPUSH listKey "1" would give me a notification but
LREM listkey -1 "1" would not yield anything even though I can see it was removed from the list

Is there a way to be notified when a value is removed from a list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, most of the operations on lists do generate events but for some reason `LREM` appears to have been forgotten. Issue [#2512](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2512) exists and your question had inspired me to propose the [fix](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/3059) so hopefully newer versions will generate these events for you.

Comment: Great thanks for the confirmation and the pending fix!